# How do I get Fragment's bundle arguments into DatePicker?

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

User inputs a date onto an EditText line on the UI.  I pass the date in a Bundle to a DatePickerDialog fragment.  I want the DatePicker dialog to show the user's date not today's date, yet today's date continues to show.  What am I missing here?

Activity file:

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardviewinput);

    fListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(R.id.FEditText);

    fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if (hasFocus && (fListenerEditText.getText().length() == 0)) {

              DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
              newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
           }
           else {
               Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
               bundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
               bundle.putInt("month", c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
               bundle.putInt("day", c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
               DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
               newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
               newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
           }
        }
    });
```

Fragment file:

```
...
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

Calendar c;
int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;

public DatePickerFragment() {
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        c =  Calendar.getInstance();
        year = getArguments().getInt("year");
        month = getArguments().getInt("month");
        day = getArguments().getInt("day");
        c.set(year, month, day);
    }
    else {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            this, year, month, day);
    picker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
    picker.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
    picker.setTitle("Select a Due Date");
    return picker;
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
     EditText txtDate = (EditText) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.FEditText);
     txtDate.setText((monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year + " ");
     txtDate.setSelection(txtDate.getText().length());
}
```

Comment: Not sure.  Am to new to Android so best way to test with log.d in Logcat?

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example of what output should I expect to see if incorrect and output if correct?

Comment: Never mind what I said above. Did you actually provide a different date in your code than the current date? Right now in the focus listener you pass the current date in the bundle and in the fragment you also revert to the current date if something is wrong. If you add this line: `...Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); c.set(1980, 5, 10);
               bundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));...rest of the code` in the focus listener you still get the current date?

Comment: I'll try that.  Be right back.

Comment: Ok I added "c.set(1980,5,10)".  I then added a date with the datepicker.  I then moved focus away and then returned focus to the EditText.  It launches the datepicker and the 1980, 5, 10 date shows correctly.

Comment: Not sure how to proceed.  It seems the bundle is not getting the year, month and day from the date...or it gets them but for some reason the fragment doesn't pull them into the datepicker.  Any thoughts?